# Implication between "to ensure" vs "ensure"

Tags: comparison

Would you help explain the difference of "ensure" between:

1. Seventeeth-century views of scientific discovery combined with social class distinctions to ensure that laboratory technicians' scientific work was never publicly acknowledged.
2. Seventeeth-century views of scientific discovery, together with social class distinctions, ensured that laboratory technicians' scientific work was never publicly acknowledged.

For the 2., it's clear that the technicians' scientific work was never publicly recognized. Does 1. also mean or imply the same meaning?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning is close, but the structures of the sentences are very very different, so the focus is different.
its indirect object, and *to ensure* introduces a purpose clause.

In the second one, the main verb is *ensured* and everything up to there is the subject.